# Paypal IPN receiving via simulator but not via my site

Tags: php, paypal

I have an odd problem, testing my IPN handler using the IPN simulator on the paypal website, it works (I've just got it emailing me the report), but when I do it through my site, I don't receive anything.

So I guess the problem must be with sending the pay request and setting the ipn url there

```
$payRequest = new PayRequest(new RequestEnvelope("en_US"), "PAY", $cancelURL, $currencyCode, $receiverList, $returnURL);
$payRequest->ipnNotificationUrl = $notifyURL;
$service = new AdaptivePaymentsService($config);
try {
   /* wrap API method calls on the service object with a try catch */
   $response = $service->Pay($payRequest);
}
```

I've double checked $notifyURL is the same as what i'm using in the simulator. Everything else is working, the user gets sent to the paypal website to complete the payment, it's just the IPN never gets sent afterwards.

Comment: is `sandbox mode` still on, as this may effect how your ipn works from your website

Comment: yes, it's still sandbox mode

Comment: try turning it off when testing live, see if you still get no response

Comment: set sandbox to false;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that IPN has to be manually turned on in one of the accounts' profile.

Comment: ...i am having the same issue...i have configured IPN into profile and enabled it...but no IPN message i am recieving while simulator working fine... can you point me how to resolve it?